# How to use scope method with belongsToMany relationship in Laravel model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a `scope` method in my model that contains belongsToMany relationship; I stuck at the point that how can I filter multiple data using scope method, that I am using at another place. My code is,

CoversAlbum.php

```
public function genres()                                                                
{  
    return $this->belongsToMany(CoversGenre::class,'covers_track_genres'); 
}
```

CoversGenre.php

```
public function albums()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(CoversAlbum::class,'covers_album_genres');
}
```

Scope method in CoversAlbum.php

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('genres', function ($q) {
        $q->where('is_present', true)();
    });
}
```

I want all the pivot `covers_genre_id` is present. Please suggest me how I can achieve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you like to include the pivot table fields? or just the conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `has` method:

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->has('genres');
}
```

Then you can do it like this:

```
CoversAlbum::active()->get();
```

This will return the list of `CoversAlbum` that has at least one `CovertsGenre`.

For more information: Look under `Querying Relation Existence` under https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [`wherePivot`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) method

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $this->genres()->wherePivot('is_present', true);
}
```